# How to list a subgroup's projects using the GitLab API?

Tags: curl, gitlab, gitlab-api

In GitLab you can create subgroups within a group and projects within those subgroups. The GitLab documentation allows you to list the subgroups of a group and the projects of a group, but I cannot find anything about listing projects of a subgroup. Does anyone know the curl command for this, or at least know that it's not supported yet?

I've tried:
`curl -s -H 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxx' https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/mygroup/subgroups/mysubgroup/projects`
`curl -s -H 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxx' https://gitlab.com/api/v4/subgroups/mysubgroup/projects`
and other similar variations with no luck so far.

Answer (score 15):

Use `%2f` to specify full path to subgroup:

```
curl -s https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/gitlab-org%2fgitter/projects
```

See this [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/29296).

Answer (score 13):

To get all the projects of group and subgroups call the api like this

```
curl --silent --header "Private-Token: YOUR_GITLAB_TOKEN" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/<group_name>/projects?include_subgroups=true
```

or using group id

```
<your_gitlab-url>/api/v4/groups/<group_ID>/projects?include_subgroups=true
```

Comment: See the next answer, this is too generic to fit with the question

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Get by groups API (Recommend)

Get All pages of the subproject:

```bash
GITLAB_API="https://<SITE>/api/v4/groups/<GROUP_NAME>/projects?include_subgroups=true&per_page=100"
PRIVATE_TOKEN="<your token>"

for ((page=1; ; page+=1)); do

  # Use cURL to get all projects
  response=$(curl --silent --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $PRIVATE_TOKEN" "$GITLAB_API&page=${page}")
  if [ $(jq length <<< "$response") -eq 0 ]; then
      break
  fi

  # Use jq to parse JSON response, extract project names, write as csv
  names=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.[] | [ .path_with_namespace] | @csv')

  # Print project names to console
  echo "$names"

done
```

Gitlab docs is [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html).

### 2. Get by project API

Get all project and filter them.

```bash
GITLAB_API="https://<SITE>/api/v4/projects?per_page=100"
PRIVATE_TOKEN="<your token>"

for ((page=1; ; page+=1)); do

  # Use cURL to get all projects
  response=$(curl --silent --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $PRIVATE_TOKEN" "$GITLAB_API&page=${page}")
  if [ $(jq length <<< "$response") -eq 0 ]; then
      break
  fi

  # Use jq to parse JSON response, extract project names, write as csv
  names=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.[] | select(.path_with_namespace | startswith("<GROUP_NAME>")) | [ .path_with_namespace] | @csv')

  # Print project names to console
  echo "$names"

done
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to list the projects of *any* group (subgroup or not) through said group ID:

See "[List a group's projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#list-a-group-s-projects)"

```
GET /groups/:id/projects
```

So first [get a list of the subgroups](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#list-a-groups-s-subgroups) in order to get their IDs, then query their projects.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That works with the numerical id, but not the actual name of the group, but I will use that as a final resort.

Answer (score 1):

To get all soubgrups of group call the v4 gitlab API like this

```
GET /groups/:id/subgroups
```